# .htaccess: Options not allowed here Centos 7

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4, centos

I am facing this error when deploy my laravel website on server centos 7 
.htaccess: Options not allowed here

```
[Sat Oct 18 09:38:43.336180 2014] [core:alert] [pid 13593] [client 182.186.240.3:7034] /home/test/public_html/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Sat Oct 18 09:38:43.727177 2014] [core:alert] [pid 13589] [client 182.186.240.3:7123] /home/test/public_html/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide this line in `<Directory...>` section of Apache config and restart Apache server in order to use `Options` directives in `.htaccess`:

```
Options All
```

As per Apache docs:

```
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
```

Comment: when i move my website ho another folder website working perfectly 
/home/test/test/public_html/

Comment: Yes that is possible as other directory section may have `Options All` directive in Apache config.